# how to can find element using selenium library with find.element on python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a function that can find the last chat on WhatsApp web and loop all chat lists with and find the last chat with the category "Kirim" and if found the last chat with that category will add a new class for Red Dot

this my code
[enter image description here][1]

but not working, maybe someone can tell me thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmO25.png